# Java Put-Request returns 400 Bad Request

Tags: java, httpclient, put, http-status-code-400

I try to perfom a put-request against a rest-api written by me, but it always returns 400-Bad Request.

> java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://localhost:8000/api/v0/contacts/2
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)

I can call the url with firefox-rest client-plugin as well as another angular client, so I guess I have configured something wrong in my java code.

The server always returns something, so I don't know, why it crashes when I try to get the input stream.

```
protected String put(String path, String parameters)
        throws IOException {

    HttpURLConnection connection = getConnection(path, "PUT", parameters);

    OutputStreamWriter outputWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(
            connection.getOutputStream());

    outputWriter.write(parameters);
    outputWriter.flush();
    outputWriter.close();

    InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String response = reader.readLine();
    while(response != null){
        response += reader.readLine();
    }
    reader.close();

    return response;
}


private HttpURLConnection getConnection(String path, String method,String params) throws MalformedURLException, IOException,
        ProtocolException {
    URL url = new URL(this.api + path);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setUseCaches(false);
    connection.setRequestMethod(method);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",
            String.valueOf(params.length()));
    return connection;
}
```

Sorry for bad english, it's not my mother tongue.

Comment: We can't really help if we don't know what kind of application the server runs (Tomcat, Spring Boot, Dropwizard) and seeing your backend code. The 400 may be due to your client missing a Content-Type, but that's just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

I did `ipconfig` in cmd prompt and  it showed `192.168.1.3`. i changed it in the place of localhost in Android app and now i am able to access local web server.